# библиотека boost

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, boost

Изменил содержимое папки boost по пути /usr/include/boost, так как не хватало некоторых библиотек. Теперь ранее работающий проект не собирается через cmake. CLion Выдаёт вот это:

/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/new_life.dir/source.cpp.o: in function `boost::thread_specific_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::formatting_context>::~thread_specific_ptr()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:61: undefined reference to`boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, void (*)(void (*)(void*), void*), void (*)(void*), void*, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/new_life.dir/source.cpp.o: in function `void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::basic_text_ostream_backend<char>::construct<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument_list_of_1<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::format, char const [25]> > >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument_list_of_1<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::format, char const [25]> > const&)':
/usr/include/boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp:145: undefined reference to`boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::basic_text_ostream_backend::construct(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::auto_newline_mode, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/new_life.dir/source.cpp.o: in function `boost::thread_specific_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::formatting_context>::reset(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::formatting_context*)':
/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:87: undefined reference to`boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, void (*)(void (*)(void*), void*), void (*)(void*), void*, bool)'

CMakeLists (до замены папки работал нормально):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(new_life)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(new_life main.cpp header.h source.cpp)
find_package (Threads REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(new_life
        ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
        )

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system log)

target_link_libraries(new_life Boost::system Boost::log)
```

В чём может быть проблема? И как правильно переустановить всю библиотеку (полностью очистить и правильно установить скаченный архив с их сайта)?

Также в конце строчка:
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Как я понял, ld - это что-то типо ярлыка в Виндус, и видимо он не туда указывает?

Comment: Не надо лазить в /usr/include/boost, это одна из папок, по которым размазывают свои файлы разные пакетные менеджеры. Собирайте нужные библиотеки boost отдельно и не засоряйте ими системные папки.

Comment: если вы прочитали всё, что написано сверху, то могли заметить, что я уже поменял содержимое этой папки (не спорю, что зря) и теперь мне интересно как восстановить работоспособность проектов, использующих библиотеку boost.

Comment: Удалить эту папку, переустановить пакеты boost, если они у вас были. Проще даже просто переустановить систему / откатить к контрольной точке.